# SharePoint Web Serivces Access Denied; Only From VS 2010

Tags: development, wss-3.0, visual-studio, web-services

After not getting much help on the last question, I decided to blow away the VM and re-create it as I already lost a week on this issue. And of course still issues, btu a little different.

I am using WSS on a 2008 server.  I removed from the SharePoint admin the blocked asmx page types.  I am using the administrator account with password and the domain, which is the IP of the VM machine.  Normally I would never recommend using the admin account, but since I am just running a test to connect to SharePoint web services, so be it.

When accessing this site via a webbrowser, no issues whatsoever.

[image]

When accessing the web services from the browser using the admin credentials, no problem.

[image]

Then when trying to access the web service via Visual Studio I get the windows security dialog;

[image]

Followed by a discovery credential for the list;

[image]

Followed by another Discovery Credential for access to the error.aspx page, but as you can see, I can see the list of services for lists.asmx;

[image]

Followed by yet another Discovery Credential asking for permission to the $metadata and this just continues continually -it will NEVER authenticate via visual studio 2010;

[image]

And then, of course, when the code is ran, what do we get - ACCESS DENIED.

Call made; code not listed makes connection.

Make call to service:

[image]

And receive the error.

[image]

[image]

And IIS for SharePoint is set top Windows Authentication and Impersonate.  All defaults.

[image]

It has now been going on 5 days; does anyone at all have any clue as to what is causing this? I have used this code and technique for years with Windows Server 2003 and WSS 2.0 and / or MOSS 2007 connecting from remote machines and NEVER, I mean NEVER had issues like this.

I would really appreciate any help.

**UPDATE**

```
_lists = new Lists
   {  //Proxy = null,
      Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName, Password, Domain),
      Url = "http://192.168.56.102/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx",
      UseDefaultCredentials = true <- Setting this to true or false throws access denied.
   }; // Reference the list object.
```

If you remove the UseDefaultCredentials completely you no longer get access denied.

```
_lists = new Lists
   {  //Proxy = null,
      Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName, Password, Domain),
      Url = "http://192.168.56.102/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx"
   }; // Reference the list object.
```

But there is still the 30-60 second lag time.  Any ideas?

Comment: Is this really a different question to http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/24462 ? If you want to add to your original question please edit it. Also you might want to keep your question as specific and succinct as possible as this will improve the chances of getting help. See [ask](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) for general guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you've checked the following?

1. Run Visual Studio as Administrator
2. VS on the same machine? Check the DisableLoopbackCheck registry property (there's a KB for this at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861 )
3. use the machine name in the username field, not the IP address (MACHINE\Administrator)

There are a few other possibilities, but these are the most common I see.

Answer (score 0):

When adding to Visual Studio you should use the URL as - http://yourserver/sites/yoursite/_vti_bin/lists.asmx?wsdl

Comment: That doesn't change anything unfortunately. :(  Thank you for the reply though...

Comment: Interestingly and surprisingly, it would appear that this has done the trick for me in Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite old: It sounds like the famous "Loopback check" error.
Try this solution here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861/en